# How to fit image into the imageview perfectly without losing image quality android

Tags: android, android-imageview, screen-resolution, image-scaling, adjustviewbounds

Im trying to fit images perfectly in the `imageView` but the image dosent fit properly when i use `centerCrop` with `adjustViewBounds` but when i use `fitXY` with `adjustViewBounds` the image fits perfectly to the imageView but now the image quality gets worst, My `imageView` `height` and `width` are `match_parent` and yes i also used `fitCenter` but didnt worked

**Screenshot**//currently im using `centerCrop` with `adjustViewBounds`

[image]

Here is my code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/Card_View"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundedCornerHome">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                android:id="@+id/imagePostHome"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
                app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundedCornerHome" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/imagepost_buttons"
                layout="@layout/imagepost_buttons" />
        </FrameLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/grey"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundedCornerHome">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/material_cardview_snipet"
                layout="@layout/material_cardview_snipet" />
        </FrameLayout>


    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

for those who want to know what is layout material_cardview_snipet ,here is the code of it

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_attach_money_24"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Ian Somerhalder"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:ignore="SmallSp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text=".............."/>



</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're image size I mean height and width ratio don't match with your image view height and width ratio glide will fit the image to center of your image view and a part of the image cuts if the ratios doesn't match.
If you force images to fit the image view even the ratios doesn't matches it will be compressed to fit either in x-axis or in y-axis. So your image don't look as original.

So use your image view attributes like this
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Here width is fixed and hight will be calculated according to the image height.

Answer (score 1):

You can resize your image in firebase, No need to code for it
https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/storage-resize-images
You can use this cool extension of firebase. it Resizes images uploaded to Cloud Storage to a specified size, and optionally keeps or deletes the original image.

it Requires a blaze plan, for that use the trial version of it or if you are a student you can use your .edu id and get it from google.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fetching images from a server or even from drawable use the **glide library** to set the image into an image view.
Google also [recommends](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics) the [Glide library](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to deal with images in android.
It's very easy to understand quickly. See [Doc](https://github.com/bumptech/glide#how-do-i-use-glide)

Comment: yes brother im using firebase and glide both ,but it dosent helps me with this issue